# Manage deep linking and app indexing both simultaneously

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

In my code below I tried to implement app indexing for Google search result as well as a deep link for some link in my website. But the problem is only app indexing is taking place and no deep linking is being done for the required link.
Is Am I doing something wrong. I tested amazon.in website and they had provided app indexing as well as deep linking for their download app banner.

I had implement deep linking for https://www.website.com/mobile-apps.html, https://m.website.com/m/mobile-apps.html, https://tv.website.com/tv/mobile-apps.html

Below is my code for app indexing as well as deep linking

```
<activity
            android:name="com.website.websiteMobileApp.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <!-- ==================For app indexing================== -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.website.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.website.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="tv.website.com" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- ==================For deep linking================== -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.website.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile-apps.html" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.website.in" android:pathPrefix="/m/mobile-apps.html" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="tv.website.com" android:pathPrefix="/tv/mobile-apps.html" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can trigger both with same url or simultaneously, but you can send whatever intent after the other one is triggered. that might solve your problem.

Comment: url for app indexing is https://website.com whereas for deep linking it is https://website.com/mobile-apps.html. Don't you think both urls are different?

Comment: Ohh i thought you are trying to trigger app indexing and deeplink simultaneously with this single url  http://www.website.com/mobile-apps.html?(i think you got me wrong, i meant to say single url)